# Thumbnail for website's link hosted by GitHub not showing on WhatsApp

Tags: html

I have a website hosted by GitHub and I wanted the thumbnail of the website's link I am sharing to show while sending it. I have found resources online about sharing link and having the thumbnail showing but none of the solution I have tried worked.

Below is an example of what I have tried to use:

```html
<head>
  <meta property="og:title" content="my-title" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="my-content" / 
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://my-website/path/" />
  <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="https://my-website/path/images/thumbnail.png" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
</head>

<body>
  <span itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="image/png"> 
          <link itemprop="url" href="https://my-website/path/images/Thumbnail.png"> 
       </span>
</body>
```

Comment: You haven't properly closed the second `meta` tag. I guess it's just a typo in your question, though

Answer (score 0):

You have a type-o in the meta tag.

```
<meta property="og:description" content="my-content" /
```

Should be closed:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="my-content" />
                                                      ▲
```

Comment: I didn't even realize that. Thank you! It works now